# How to disable or delete Ubuntu Desktop geoip-database?

Tags: 14.04, delete, geoip, geolocation

So, I found out why geoip-database is used in Ubuntu, but it seems it is intrustive. So, can you disable it or delete it? If so, will that interferer with Ubuntu performance?

Comment: You might want to see the answer here  https://askubuntu.com/questions/233096/why-does-ubuntu-desktop-require-geoip-database before making a decision.

Comment: @Terrance I did read that question and its answers. In all honesty, all that he has mentioned is not necessarily important. I have already found the solution and gone ahead and removed and purged the packages. I will post an answer to my question.

Comment: That's alright.  I was only showing that to you to help you with your decision.  Glad you got your answer.  =)